# Image upload to a server using $_FILES doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have a html file which select images from user's computer.code is given bellow

```
//index.php
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/uploader/upload.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
            Please choose a photo: 
            <input name="photo" type="file"><br/><br/>
            Say something about this photo: 
            <input name="message" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
        </form>
    </body>  
</html>
```

when the user clicked 'upload' button, user is redirected to uploader.php file. Code of the upload.php is given bellow

```
<?php 
//upload.php
if(isset($_FILES['photo']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

    $uploadfile = './uploads/'.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

    $iStats=getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

    if (isset($iStats['mime']) && $iStats[0]>0) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
        include_once 'fbmain.php';
        try{
            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
            $me = $facebook->api('/me');
            $token = $session['access_token'];//here I get the token from the $session array
            $album_id = '2179901265385';//MY ALBUM ID
            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
            $args = array('message' => $_POST['message']);
            $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($uploadfile);

            $data = $facebook->api('/'. $album_id . '/photos?access_token='. $token, 'post', $args);

        } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            echo "Error:" .$e;
        }
        unlink($uploadfile);
        echo "Success!\n";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong file type!\n";
    }
}

?>
```

I have created a folde named 'uploads' in same directory. **when the user upload a file it first uploaded to 'uploads' folder and then to facebook.**
**This work fine in localhost. But it doesn't work when it is in the server.It gives me 'Wrong file type!' message.** Note that **I have the write permission in my server for 'uploads' folder.**
I tried to print the value of '$_FILES'.

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

It gives me this output

```
Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => TEST IMAGE.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 2 [size] => 0 ) )
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I hope you changed the form action "http://localhost/uploader/upload.php" to direct to a script on your server?

Comment: `tmp_name` is empty so you probably should check if PHP has the rights to write files to /tmp directory (or to where-ever it is configured to write temporary files)

Comment: Also please consider to check `safe_mode` status in configuration file.

Comment: @Andris Can you please tell me how to check that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

error 2 means file is too big... MAX_FILE_SIZE is in bytes

Comment: Yes that's correct.Thanks. I just changed MAX_FILE_SIZE to a higher value. Now it works